# Getting "Undefined symbols" when trying to use EventKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, eventkit, undefined-symbol

I am trying to use EventKit based around the doco & SimpleEKDemo application, however I am getting the following single error.

What does this error mean and what steps would be recommended for troubleshooting (first time I've had such a linking error & I'm a bit lost - I've parsed through my code versus teh example code and I can't see any obvious differences).

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-EKEventStore in AppointmentListController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that in the header file from the controller I'm using the event kit code I do have:

```
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if you have added EventKit and EventKitUI frameworks to link with your target?

Comment: ummmm....I guess I don't understand what you mean so probably not :)  I've just the done the #import statements but I guess this is different.  Is this something in project build options or something?

Comment: Nice quick fix! I forgot to add FrameWork after importing a view controller from another project.

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgot any of below things

1. add eventKitFramwork in Your project
2. Import this framework in your file #import